# bootbox confirm not working when inside a <form> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I've the following code

html:

```
<div class="portlet-body">
<div class="table">
    <table class="table table-advance table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><strong>#</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Status</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Mobile No</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Phone No</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Email</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Litigation</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Address</strong></th>
            <th colspan="2"><strong>Actions</strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><span class="label label-md label-danger">Rejected</span></td>
            <td>Mr Name One Ahmed</td>
            <td>441254226688</td>
            <td>441254226688</td>
            <td><a href="mailto:zeeah@mail.co.uk">zeeah@mail.co.uk</a></td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>5 (Flat 12 ) Temple Street, <br />Nelson, Lanca's, BB95SS</td>

            <form method="post" action="/legalHQ/public/admin/PIClaimant.php" class="mysubmitClass" id="deleteform" >
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_pi_claimant_id" value="9">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_case_id" value="1">
                    <input type="submit" name="edit" id="btnEdit" class="btn purple btn-xs" value=" &nbsp; Edit &nbsp; " />
                </td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="delete" id="btnDelete" class="btn red btn-xs myconfirm" value=" Delete " /></td>
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><span class="label label-md label-warning">Submitted</span></td>
            <td>Mr Name Two Ahmed</td>
            <td>441254226688</td>
            <td>441254226688</td>
            <td><a href="mailto:zeeah@mail.co.uk">zeeah@mail.co.uk</a></td>
            <td>Yes Litigation</td>
            <td>5 (Flat 2 ) Temple Street, <br />Nelson, Lanca's, BB95SS</td>

            <form method="post" action="/legalHQ/public/admin/PIClaimant.php" class="mysubmitClass" id="deleteform " >
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_pi_claimant_id" value="10">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_case_id" value="1">
                    <input type="submit" name="edit" id="btnEdit" class="btn purple btn-xs" value=" &nbsp; Edit &nbsp; " />
                    </td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="delete" id="btnDelete" class="btn red btn-xs myconfirm" value=" Delete " /></td>
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><span class="label label-md label-success">Accepted and Signed</span></td>
            <td>Mr Name Five Ahmed</td>
            <td>441254226688</td>
            <td>441254226688</td>
            <td><a href="mailto:zeeah@mail.co.uk">zeeah@mail.co.uk</a></td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>33 Temple Street, <br />Nelson, Lanca's, BB95SS</td>

            <form method="post" action="/legalHQ/public/admin/PIClaimant.php" class="mysubmitClass" id="deleteform " >
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_pi_claimant_id" value="12">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_case_id" value="1">
                    <input type="submit" name="edit" id="btnEdit" class="btn purple btn-xs" value=" &nbsp; Edit &nbsp; " />
                </td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="delete" id="btnDelete" class="btn red btn-xs myconfirm" value=" Delete " /></td>
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td><span class="label label-md label-success">Accepted</span></td>
            <td>Mr Name Seven Ahmed</td>
            <td>441254226688</td>
            <td>441254226688</td>
            <td><a href="mailto:zeeah@mail.co.uk">zeeah@mail.co.uk</a></td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>5 (Flat 2 ) Temple Street, <br />Nelson, Lanca's, BB95SS</td>

            <form method="post" action="/legalHQ/public/admin/PIClaimant.php" class="mysubmitClass" id="deleteform " >
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_pi_claimant_id" value="13">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_case_id" value="1">
                    <input type="submit" name="edit" id="btnEdit" class="btn purple btn-xs" value=" &nbsp; Edit &nbsp; " />
                </td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="delete" id="btnDelete" class="btn red btn-xs myconfirm" value=" Delete " /></td>
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery is below:

```
$('.myconfirm').click(function(){
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
       alert("Confirm result: "+result);
       // return (result) ? true : false;
    }); 
});
```

Now I've amended the code with all the forms and data its all fake data though but i want to delete record after confirm dialog box so i asked the question.

bootbox works fine if it is not wrapped around `<form>` tag, but when inside, it does not work.I don't know what is the issue.

Any Idea?

Comment: Any css you write related to the form?

Comment: its bootstrap im using

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle

Comment: What u mean by does not work ? What is problem with This fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6264/

Comment: Thank you @PratikJoshi but still not working on my site... :(

Comment: @UsmanSharifAmjadKhan , Please tell me IS fiddle Working as u expected   ?

Comment: It work the way you showed me on jsFiddle but not returning true or false to perform appropriate action. if you can see my returned values which are commented in my code when i applied those no result dont know why

Comment: @PratikJoshi if you remove the e.preventDefault() then check the results...

Comment: Check Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6265/, is this u want after all , If OK is clicked ,then submit form ,else not

Comment: @PratikJoshi I've never used JSFiddle i'm trying it to learn... :(

Comment: @UsmanSharifAmjadKhan , OK please check fiddle Link above

Comment: Sorry i should have posted it in answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6265/)

Use following code:

```
$('.myconfirm').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
      // alert("Confirm result: "+result);
        if(result==true){

            $('form').submit();
        }
       // return (result) ? true : false;
    }); 
});
```

In bootstrap ,Check Which button on Confirm box is clicked? It can be either Yes ,or No. If the result is Yes then submit the form.But if user clicks on No/Cancel .Dont submit the form.

Comment: just a question I've multiple forms which are auto generated in PHP while loop i don't have any control how many there would be, therefore i dont want to submit the form only it worked but does not execute the code which it was working before having that bootbox confirm dialog box. any reason why?

Comment: U mean there are multiple forms ? Ok Please edit the Question and Add HTML of 2,3 Forms.

Comment: I think problem might be Because u have multiple forms , if confirm on form Number 1 is there then form Number 1 should get submitted.Correct? CHECK THIS FIDDLE jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6270

Comment: @UsmanSharifAmjadKhan , thanks :) you can also do +1 if it satisfies your question.